# Can you create an array for functions?

Tags: array, pointer, functions

Let's say I want to create 10 functions, named Function1, Function2 until 10. Each function is used if a certain variable is equal to its number. Rather than using individual functions, I was wondering if its possible to use some sort of array concept for functions when it comes to naming? I tried reading about it and saw pointers but I honestly didn't understand what I saw about it because I'm not that adept to the language yet.

Comment: Of course this is possible, you can make an array of any data type you like. And a function pointer is a data type. But this is a broad issue, so you rather get a good book or online resource on C++ and start to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how to do it:

**jump_table.ino**

```cpp
int func1(int arg)  { return arg + 1; }
int func2(int arg)  { return arg + 2; }
int func3(int arg)  { return arg + 3; }
int func4(int arg)  { return arg + 4; }
int func5(int arg)  { return arg + 5; }
int func6(int arg)  { return arg + 6; }
int func7(int arg)  { return arg + 7; }
int func8(int arg)  { return arg + 8; }
int func9(int arg)  { return arg + 9; }
int func10(int arg) { return arg + 10; }

int (*jump_table[10])(int) = { func1, func2, func3, func4, func5, 
                               func6, func7, func8, func9, func10 };
    
void setup() {
}
    
void loop() {
  int index = 2;
  int argument = 42;
  int result = (*jump_table[index])(argument);
  // result is 45
}
```

All functions stored in the array must have the same signature.  This simply means that they must return the same type (e.g. `int`) and have the same arguments (a single `int` in the example above).

---

You can do the same with *static* class methods (but not instance methods).  For example you could use `MyClass::myStaticMethod` in the array above but not `MyClass::myInstanceMethod` nor `instance.myInstanceMethod`:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  static int myStaticMethod(int foo)   { return foo + 17; }
  int        myInstanceMethod(int bar) { return bar + 17; }
}

MyClass instance;
```

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-can-i-use-an-array-of-function-pointers) over on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, is argument different from arg? But it seems like your code is correct.

Comment: @AndroidV11 The value of `argument` gets passed to the appropriate function where it available as `arg` (or `foo` in the class example).  BTW, based on your comment it sounds like you're pretty new to programming.  If that's the case I'd recommend learning more of the basics of C++ before you use this technique; it's fairly advanced and really only makes sense to use in specialized situations (e.g. remote procedure call handlers).

Comment: @AndroidV11 I just fixed a rather nasty typo in the code.  C++ uses zero-based array indices so to call the third function `index` needs to be `2`, not `3`.